# Get the result from Select and Update the selected records in the same statement

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, apache-camel

I want to select few records from the database table and then change the value a column from 'Pending' to 'Processing' n the database. But the result from the Select statement has to go to a jms queue for processing.
I am using Apache Camel framework for integration and MS SQL Server 2005 as database.
It would nice if this can be achieved by a single sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the `UPDATE` and use the [`OUTPUT/OUTPUT INTO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) feature to return the rows in a result set http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/05/25/using-the-output-and-output-into-clauses-in-sql-server-2005/